# How to code to use pinv() in matlab function from multi equations?

Tags: matlab

I've got some equation as following.

*f(x)=3x^3−4x^2+3x−7*

*f(x)=2x^3−3x^2+2x−1*

## I want get a X  from  AX=B, X=pinv(A)B.

then I have coded in MATLAB as following.

A = [ 3 −4 3 -7 ;
     2 −3 2 −1 ];

## But I don't know how to get a B? Does anyone know how to get B?

What am I supposed to do B?

Comment: the first row of `A` does not make sense. Shouldn't it read `[3 -4 3 -7]`?

Comment: B is what you want to equal you equation to. b is `f(x)`

Comment: @Benoit_11 Sorry my typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pinv() is for the solution of sets of linear equations, for example multiple equations of the following form: ax + by + cz.

What you seem to have is several cubic equations , i.e. of the form ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d. Assuming you are trying to solve each for f(x) = 0, I would use the roots() function. For example, for your first equation:

```
f1 = [3 -4 3 -7]
f1_roots = roots(f1)
```

See here for roots documentation: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html

It doesn't really make sense to treat your two equations as simultaneous equations, as there is no one value for *x* that will satisfy both solutions. If you wish to find the value for *x* that is as close as possible to both solutions but (does not satisfy either equation), you could consider using least squares, as explained by bashfuloctopus https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392818/how-can-i-use-left-inverse-to-fx-3x-format-equation/1392843?noredirect=1#comment2835591_1392843

Comment: I think it should be like this X=pinv(A)B. not roots

Comment: As it's not a linear equation it cannot be expressed as AX = B.

Comment: But someone give solver like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392818/how-can-i-use-left-inverse-to-fx-3x-format-equation/1392843?noredirect=1#comment2835591_1392843          Please find bashfuloctopus's answer

Comment: Might be I think you are right. It's not a linear equation. We can not  be expressed ax=b. Then what am I suppose to do to get a solve? Would you let me know hint or idea please?

Comment: Are you trying to find a value for _x_ that satisfies all your equations? There isn't one. Using the `roots` approach, you can find a value for _x_ that solves equation 1, and then a value for _x_ that solves equation 2. Using bashhfuloctopus' approach you can find a single value for _x_ that gets close to satisfying both equations, but in practice doesn't satisfy either.

Comment: would you please update in your answer? I can't quite a catch your comment. I have been up vote. Oh I need more reputation. then I have marked it.